# How to get specific global package (module) of python in venv?

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-venv

I had installed TensorFlow of 586 MB in my ubuntu now if I create any venv environment I have to redownload it in the venv. is there any way by that I can get the TensorFlow from global to my venv without downloading or having extra modules.

Answer (score 1):

Normally *pip* wouldn't need to download *tensorflow* again, as it keeps copies of downloaded artifacts in a local *cache* on the file system. But it would need to install it in each *virtual environment*, unless...

Maybe *venv*'s `--system-site-packages` option is what you are looking for:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html?highlight=system%20site%20packages#creating-virtual-environments

Comment: `--system-site-packages` but this gets my all environment package. I want specific TensorFlow to be in venv

Comment: As said, it will only install it fresh, but not download again. That's the current compromise. There are ways to avoid a new installation, but none of them are really production ready. -- Although, if I am not mistaken it's a bit better with [_conda_](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/), so you might want to read on this and give it a try.